# Check user logged in Joomla 2.5 from external script (reiterated)

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm well familiar with coding in PHP and other languages, but I'm totally unfamiliar with Joomla.

What I want to accomplish is to know when a user has logged in on the Joomla site (under /web) and differentiate this script's behaviour accordingly.

I have a Joomla 2.5 site under /web/ and I have a script under /web/test/index.php, where the following code lies (**collected from other replies in here** and elsewhere):

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
echo dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "\n";
if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php'))
    include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php';

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();

print_r(JFactory::getUser());
```

What I get back is

```
/web
JUser Object
(
    [isRoot:protected] => 
    [id] => 0
    [name] => 
    ...
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Use this code it's working:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/' ));

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');

var_dump(JFactory::getUser());
```